# ZF2 How to pass value as expression in where clause

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I need to use like this  WHERE clause

```
$where->expression('YEARWEEK(create_date, 1)=?', 'YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)');
```

IN plain php we use like below sql :

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please elaborate more your question and give some context on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this one should be straight forward.

```
$where = new Where();
$sql = new Sql($adapter);
$select = $sql->select();
$where->addPredicate(new Predicate\Expression('YEARWEEK(create_date, 1)=YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1)'));
$select->from('your_table')->where($where);
```

Comment: The output of sql  is below the  'YEAR(CURDATE())' is enclosed within quotes . So its not converted to expression 
<br>
SELECT `first_name` AS `first_name` FROM `table_name` WHERE YEAR(add_date)='YEAR(CURDATE())'

Comment: well. lets just remove =?, its not needed anyways